my code using mobx doesn't update the state
I have a simple code, I'm new to mobx, its easier in context but I had to use mobx :
import { makeAutoObservable } from "mobx";
import booksRepository from "../Books/Books.repository";

class BookStore {
  books = [];
  showPrivateBooks = false;

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  async loadBooks() {
    const books = await booksRepository.getBooks(this.showPrivateBooks);
    this.books = [...books];
  }

  async addBook(newBook) {
    await booksRepository.addBook(newBook);
    await this.loadBooks();
  }

  async toggleShowPrivateBooks() {
    this.showPrivateBooks = !this.showPrivateBooks;
    await this.loadBooks();
  }
}

const bookStore = new BookStore();
export default bookStore;

and the index.js:
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";
import bookStore from "./Store/BookStore";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    bookStore.loadBooks();
  }, []);

  const handleAddBook = async () => {
    const newBook = {
      name: "Book",
      ownerId: "postnikov",
      author: "Someone",
    };
    await bookStore.addBook(newBook);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => bookStore.toggleShowPrivateBooks()}>
          {bookStore.showPrivateBooks ? "Show All Books" : "Show Private Books"}
        </button>
      </div>
      {bookStore.books.map((book, i) => (
        <div key={i}>
          {book.author}: {book.name}
        </div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={handleAddBook}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const ObservedApp = App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ObservedApp />, rootElement);



but, the toggle button doesn't work.
It looks like the store is updating but the data on the screen doesn't change
Once I press the button, the store updates, and new data is loaded but the UI does not change
you can find the full code here codesandbox

You need to wrap your App (and basically every component that uses any data from MobX store) with observer HOC:
import { observer } from "mobx-react";

const App = observer(...)

https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html#react-integration
